Linking a different stylesheet in View Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Webjinny::Frontend#index
Showing /home/krapirastogi/webjinny/app/views/layouts/webjinny/default_theme.html.erb where line #15 raised:
The asset "default_theme/css/default.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.
My view file in engine .. Default_theme.html.erb inside layouts/myengine/default_theme
<head>
  <title>Default_theme</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <!-- Mobile Metas -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <!-- Site Metas -->
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'default_theme/css/default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>

</head>

The engine.rb file looks like this
module Webjinny
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Webjinny

    # Precompile specific assets
    initializer 'webjinny.assets.precompile' do |app|
      app.config.assets.precompile += %w( default_theme/css/default.css )
    end

    # Add custom asset paths
    initializer 'webjinny.assets.paths' do |app|
      app.config.assets.paths << Webjinny::Engine.root.join('app', 'apps', 'themes', 'default_theme', 'assets', 'css')

    end
end
end

The location of the file is here--
webjinny/
app/
apps/
themes/
default_theme/
assets/
css/
default.css
How do I link it ? Where is the mistake ? How do you render stylesheets from a folder in a rails Engine ?

Add a new asset path, it can be anywhere you like:
initializer "webjinny.assets.paths" do |app|
  app.config.assets.paths << root.join("app/apps/themes")
end

Precompile path is relative to your asset path:
initializer "webjinny.assets.precompile" do |app|
  app.config.assets.precompile += %w(default_theme/assets/css/default.css)
end

Then reference what you're precompiling (relative to asset path):
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "default_theme/assets/css/default", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload" %>


By default the engine runs on test/dummy so that was creating a problem when   app.config.assets.paths << root.join("app/apps/themes")

How can you render a custom layout just like the stylesheet , what if my layout is in a different folder inside a theme?

that's a separate question

when should we define stylesheet path in assets.rb in config folder in engine? Or should we define in lib folder?

in the engine, convention is to create named initializers in engine.rb file with initializer method.
